# how to send an arraylist as a request to server to compare the contacts present in server and arraylist?

Tags: android

I am creating an application in which I have to pass an arraylist to server as a request. If contacts present in arraylist and the server are matched then they should be identified.. How can I send arraylist as a request? Is this possible?

Comment: This question is very broad. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to convert the array list to JSON. Then send the request with json data.

For example:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Robin");
list.add("John");
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(list);
String dataToSend = jsonArray.toString();
```

`dataToSend` will contain the formated json string that you could put in a param in send to the server.

Comment: do you have any idea on how to compare two numbers in android?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a server you've programmed yourself, one another solution is to send the data present in the ArrayList, one element by one and to recreate it on the server on the same time adding values little by little.
Else JSON seems a good solution.